# Can have simultaneously at onClick function props and a function at reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Hello i have a modal with two buttons

```
           <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.handleModalOpen}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Fill this form to continue</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>This is the modal </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.handleModalOpen}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>(myhadler,props.handleModalOpen)}>
                    Save Changes
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
```

On onClick i want to trigger a function that called

```
     myhandler
```

and close the modal if the button is pressed with

```
    props.handleModalOpen.
```

The props.handleModalOpen is communicating with other component that is the parent. My problem is that when i pressed the button my function myhandler in not working and the only that i achive is to close the modal. Is there a way to run simultaneously my function and the props.handleModalOpen without problem

The function

```
  myhandler
```

is used to save the form data in local storage

Comment: why don't you combine the two of them ? for ex `onClick = () => myFunction()` and in myFunction you do your `myhadler` logic and call `props.handleModalOpen` ? It's better  to have logic inside a component function and not polute the HTML(jsx)  with logic. Use JSX just for calling the methods you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `myHandler()` in callback's scope and add a state if the button opened with `handleModalOpen`

```
const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

<Modal.Footer>
  <Button
    variant="secondary"
    onClick={() => {
      props.handleModalOpen();
      setIsOpened(true);
    }}
  >
    Close
  </Button>
  <Button
    variant="primary"
    onClick={() => {
      myHandler();
      if (isOpened) {
        props.handleModalOpen();
        setIsOpened(false);
      }
    }}
  >
    Save Changes
  </Button>
</Modal.Footer>
```